# How to know if something ran or not with cron

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I'm using cron scheduler (quartz) and for some reasons (server down...) sometimes a task don't trigger. I wan't to check if task ran or not. My idea was to do that based on cron: I get previous fire date (for example: 0 7 11 4 * ? = At 11:07:00am, on the 4th day, every month I should have 2018/07/04) and I compare it to the latest task's date (got it in db): if it's different then I know task didn't run.

My problem is getting previous fire date.
I tried suggestions here: [Finding Last Fired time using a Cron Expression in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710883/finding-last-fired-time-using-a-cron-expression-in-java) as `trigger.getPreviousFireTime();`But still not working... No problem getting next fire time but impossible to get previous fire time (having null or wrong date).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the syslog.  Depending on which *nix you're using, you can run:

```
grep cron (location)
```

and get the data you want.  From there you can process it however you like.

[Ubuntu Cron Log Location Linky](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log)

I'd personally use this SO question to get the output of this call from Java:

[Call a command from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792024/how-to-execute-system-commands-linux-bsd-using-java)

And as a final note, using:

```
grep cron /var/log/syslog | tail -1
```

will get you just the last line.  On my Linux-based server, the line looks like this:

```
Jul 10 12:17:01 ---------- junk removed -------------------
```

I would take the first 15 characters of that and parse it.

Comment: Didnt know that thank's, any way to get it directly in java ?

Comment: Answer edited for Java advice, which I admit is minimal.